# A function is not returning, but console.log is showing the content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

I am making a function that will render the information of fees in each installment(key is equal to installment1, card[1][key] is the value, like a float 2.5), but my function is not returning!
The console.log is working perfectly, anyone can give me an insight?!

```
export function returnInstallmentsWithFee(card, fee) {
   Object.keys(card[1]).forEach(function (key) {
      console.log('test', key, card[1][key])
      return (
        <div>
          {key}:{card[1][key]}
         </div>
      )
   })
}
```

Comment: what do you mean it's not returning? sure there's no return statement, but that means it returns `undefined`

Comment: Can you console.log where your recieve the return. To see exactly what it's returning? What does it say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. your top level function (`returnInstallmentsWithFee`) doesn't have a return satatement;
2. `forEach` doen't return anything, you may want to use `.map()`

```
export function returnInstallmentsWithFee(card, fee) {
      return Object.keys(card[1]).map(function (key) {
        console.log('test', key, card[1][key])
        return (
          <div>
            {key}:{card[1][key]}
          </div>
        )
      })
    }
```

Comment: 2 big errors, thanks for the help! Need to wait more 6 minutes to select as the correct answer, but now I can sleep, really, thank you!